# Mostrar un vector de objetos en un JtextArea (Java)

Tags: java

Estoy intentando desarrollar una aplicación gráfica que consta en almacenar contactos y mostrarlos

en un jtextArea(Area).

La aplicación está  compuesta de una clase llamada contactos y de  varios frame entre ellos uno principal

desde el cual se ejecutarán otros frames llamados desde las opciones de un

menú(frame principal).

En el primer frame tengo declarado un  atributo estático (vector de objetos) **public static Contacto

vContacto[] = new Contacto[5];** y dos eventos de tipo MouseClicked llamados LlenarMouseClickedy

MostrarMouseClicked.

Al pulsar el primer evento (LlenarMouseClickedy ) nos saltaría una pantalla con

dos jtextfield(textNombre,TextTelefono) donde almacenaré el nombre y el número de

teléfono del contacto y tendríamos que pulsar un jbutton para almacenarlo en el

vector vContacto[].

El problema que tengo es que cuando almaceno los contactos y pulso el evento MostrarMouseClicked

que sirve para mostrar los contactos en un jTextArea(Area),  no se me muestran en el.

No se que tengo mal, espero que me puedan ayudar.

PD:
En la clase llenar uso un metodo llamado posLibre para recorrer el vecctor y ver

si en este se puden almacenar contactos.

```
private int posLibre() {
    pos = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Principal.vContacto.length; i++) {
        if (Principal.vContacto[i] == null) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
}
```

Un saludo.

```
public class Contacto {

String nombre;
long numero;

public Contacto(String nombre, long numero) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.numero = numero;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public long getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(long numero) {

    this.numero = numero;
}

@Override 
public String toString() {


    return "Contacto:\n" + "nombre=" + nombre + "numero=" + numero + '\n';
}
```

---

```
 public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static Contacto vContacto[] = new Contacto[5];
private Mostrar m = new Mostrar();

public Principal() {
    initComponents();
    m.mostrar();
}  private void LlenarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    Llenar a = new Llenar();
    a.setVisible(true);


}                                   

private void MostrarMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    Mostrar b = new Mostrar();
    b.setVisible(true);


}}
```

---

```
public class Llenar extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int pos = 0;


public Llenar() {
    initComponents();

}

private void btnAñadirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String nombre, telefono;
    long tel;
    if (txtNombre.getText().trim().equals("") && txtTelefono.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Introduce nombre" + "\n" + "Telefono no válido", "Mensaje", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } else if (txtNombre.getText().trim().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Introduce nombre", "Mensaje", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } else if (txtTelefono.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Telefono no válido", "Mensaje", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } else {
        pos = posLibre();
        nombre = txtNombre.getText().trim();
        telefono = txtTelefono.getText();
        tel = Long.parseLong(telefono);
        if (pos == -1) {
            txtNombre.setText(null);
            txtTelefono.setText(null);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vector lleno", "Mensaje", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        } else {
            Principal.vContacto[pos] = new Contacto(nombre, tel);
            txtNombre.setText(null);
            txtTelefono.setText(null);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contacto añadido", "Mensaje", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}                                         

private void txtTelefonoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();

    if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
        evt.consume();
    }


}                                    
private int posLibre() {
    pos = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Principal.vContacto.length; i++) {
        if (Principal.vContacto[i] == null) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En principio yo no veo problema en el llenado del array. Para asegurarte, deberías imprimir en consola (lo más facil para ver si funciona) todo el array después de la instrucción donde introduces un nuevo contacto. Para comprobar que se ha introducido correctamente.

Si no te muestra los resultados debe de ser cosa de la clase mostrar. Porque a mí la lógica del programa me dice que se introducen correctamente los datos

Comment: Ves hacia atrás en el código. Si nada más introducir los datos al Array imprimes el Array y no te imprime nada, entonces deberías de probar qué es lo que tienen las variables String que usas para construir el objeto que metes en el array. Así retrocedes en el camino que los datos recorren a lo largo de tu programa.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me lo  imprime en consola ,pero si llamo al metodo desde el evento  MostrarMouseClicked y no desde el contructor del la clase principal ,además ,en el jtetxArea sigue sin mostrarse los contactos . Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)